# how send parent iframe referral to php

Tags: php, sql, iframe, referrals

i insert a button on my site and i use `$refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` to get the referral, but always display the URL where the iframe is embed, is any way to send the original referral to the iframe? because i want to know if the user comes from facebook, twitter, etc, but always send me my own URL, i try something like this:

```
    <script>
    var myval = ""+escape(parent.document.referer);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'downs.php',
      data: {'variable': myval},
    });
    </script>
```

i know is wrong but i don't know how send the parent referral to my php

Answer (score -1):

```
you can try this js code this will help you to get parent url

var pathname = window.parent.location.href
```

Comment: but im not trying to get the parent URL, i'm trying to get the referral address that comes from external services